# Do I need to repeat a RewriteCond in my .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have three domains - *domain.com*, *domain.co.uk* and *domain.ru*. I'm trying to achieve the following redirects in one .htaccess file:

- all requests should be redirected to include the prefix *www.*
- all requests to (www.)domain.com should be redirected to www.domain.co.uk
- all requests on http should be redirected to use https

Following the documentation provided by the host, a little search-foo (and much head scratching), I have pieced-together the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?domain\.(com|co.uk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?domain.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It actually appears to work OK, but I don't really know what *RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on* does, and I'm wondering if the logic is flawed.

Because of the set-up on the host, it shouldn't ever occur that the first condition be true, while the second and third conditions be false. But for the other conditions, the way I see it is:

- if the first and second conditions are true, then execute the first rule;
- if the first condition is true, the second condition is false, but the third is true, then execute the second rule;

So what if the first condition is false? What will happen? Does the logic ignore the second condition and move on to the third one, or would it just exit at that point? If that's the case, then perhaps I should repeat the first condition after the first rule, so it works for both scenarios?

Is there a better/correct/more succinct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Conditions between the previous rule and the current rule are applied to that rule. So in the example below, #1, #2 and #3 belong with each other and #4 and #5 belong with each other. Rule #3 gets executed if #1, #2 and #3 are true. Rule #5 gets executed if #4 and #5 are true. I believe mod_rewrite first evaluates the first argument of `RewriteRule`, then evaluates any conditions associated with that rule. If all are true (or some of them are true with the `[OR]` flag present), the url will be rewritten based on the second argument of `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteCond #1
RewriteCond #2
RewriteRule #3

RewriteCond #4
RewriteRule #5
```

As for the condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on`:

This checks if the `X-Forwarded-SSL` header is not present. This header will be present if the client contacted your outer server with HTTP with SSL, and the outer server communicates with an inner server over HTTP without SSL. The inner server would not know that the initial request was with SSL, and would send back a response to the outer server, and then to the client to redirect to https. Since this was already the case, this would result in an infinite loop. You probably don't need it unless you specifically set that up. If only part of the connection is encrypted it might be vulnerable to eavesdropping or a mitm attack if someone has access to the network with unencrypted traffic.